# Webscraping using Javascript

Tags: javascript, express, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape contents of multi page website using javascript and export it to excel or csv file.

The problem is I only scrape first page and I'm unable to export it to excel or csv.

here's my code so far

```
const PORT =8000
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const url = 'https://www.taneps.go.tz/epps/viewAllAwardedContracts.do?d-3998960-p=1&selectedItem=viewAllAwardedContracts.do&T01_ps=100'
axios(url)
 .then(response => {
    const html = response.data
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    const articles = []
    $('#T01',html).each(function(){
        const contract = $(this).text()
        articles.push({
            contract
        })
        
    })
    console.log(articles)
   
 }).catch(err => console.log(err))



app.listen(PORT,() => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

I want to scrape all pages and store it in csv or excel file

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```js
import axios from "axios"
import {load} from "cheerio"
import fs from "fs"


const data_to_csv = (arr) => {
    const array = [].concat(arr)
    return array.map(el => {
        return Object.values(el).toString()
    }).join('\n') + '\n'
  }

const get_data = async (page) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://www.taneps.go.tz/epps/viewAllAwardedContracts.do?d-3998960-p=${page}&selectedItem=viewAllAwardedContracts.do&T01_ps=100`)
        const html = response.data
        const $ = load(html)
        const data = []
        $('#T01>tbody>tr').each((_idx, el) => {
            const tender_no = $(el).find('td:nth-child(1)').text()
                .replace(/(\s+)/g, '')
                .replace(/,/g, '.')
            const procuring_entity = $(el).find('td:nth-child(2)').text()
                .replace(/(\s\s+)/g, '')
            const supplier_name = $(el).find('td:nth-child(3)').text()
                .replace(/(\s\s+)/g, '')
            const award_date = $(el).find('td:nth-child(4)').text()
                .replace(/(\s\s+)/g, '')
            const award_amount = $(el).find('td:nth-child(5)').text()
                .replace(/(\s\s+)/g, '')
            data.push({
                "Tender No": tender_no, 
                "Procuring Entity": procuring_entity, 
                "Supplier Name": supplier_name, 
                "Award Date": award_date, 
                "Award Amount": award_amount
            })
        });
        return data
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    get_data(i).then((data) => {
        console.log(`Page number: ${i}`)
        fs.appendFileSync("taneps.csv", data_to_csv(data))
    })
}
```

Output csv file `taneps.csv`

```
PA/009/2021-22/HQ/G/19-,Muhimbili National Hospital,BADRA ATHUMAN NDULLAH,11/10/2021 11:29:36,451350.00(TZS)
PA/058/2021-2022/G/22,Mkwawa University College of Education,IANMAC TECHNOLOGIES,12/11/2021 17:03:52,1413000.00(TZS)
PA/055/2021-2022/HQ/NC/08,Institute of Social Work,LUMINA INVESTMENTS LIMITED,11/11/2021 08:02:03,2343480.00(TZS)
```

Tested on `Node v16.15.0` Used `axios v1.1.3` and `cheerio v1.0.0-rc.12`